# Having trouble making sure I have the latest version of .NET Core installed

Tags: .net, .net-core

I installed .NET Core on my Mac following this guide: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

The guide says I am installing .NET Core 1.1. All the latest documentation I am studying says.NET Core 1.1 is the latest, project.json is dead and so is .xproj. No problem, I do not care that I still gotta read some xml with .csproj, we do not live in a perfect world.

But the installation says that I am installing .NET Core 1.0.3, not 1.1:
[image]

And from terminal:
[image]

So I am confused, looks like .NET Core 1.0.3 to me, not 1.1. Perhaps on Windows the latest version is .NET Core 1.1?

Comment: It would probably help if you chose a title for your question that does not invite downvotes.

Comment: @MikeNakis your opinion I am not inviting down votes, I am being succinct, that is my question and it summarizes my confusion or problem well.

Comment: @MikeNakis and you can see there is already a clear answer that has helped me

Comment: Of course it is my opinion.  I don't express other people's opinions.  I express mine.

Comment: @MikeNakis Stackoverflow is a forum that strives to provide primarily factual information, primarily opinion based information should be avoided on this forum.

Comment: First of all, I am the guy who upvoted your question when it was at -1.  Secondly, I was trying to give you a hint as to how to help yourself so that your question might fare better.  Thirdly, opinions are discouraged on *answers*, but they are fine on comments.  Actually, that's what comments are for.

Comment: @MikeNakis my bad, thanks for trying to help ;)

Comment: Well, I am sure I could have made a better choice of words in my comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse version of .NET Core and .NET Core SDK. You have SDK 1.0.3

To check .NET version, you run in cmd:

```
dotnet
```

[image]

Please see [this version explanation](http://thedatafarm.com/dotnet/dotnet-core-version-confusion/):

> When you are at the dotnet command line (aka the CLI aka Command Line
>   Interface) and type ‘dotnet’ you will be shown the version of the
>   runtime.
>
> When you add the version parameter (‘dotnet –version’) that will
>   return the version of the SDK (aka CLI aka Command Line Interface)
>   that you are working with.

Comment: Going to be honest, but it's not guaranteed to tell you the version of the ".NET Core". Sadly, there's no version that means ".NET Core". There's a *host*, a *runtime* and an *sdk* and each has their own version. `dotnet` tells you the version of the *host*. Sadly, there's no command to show the version of the *runtime* (corefx/coreclr). I look at files as [I described here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net-core/9592/components-and-versioning-in-net-core/29628/identifying-versions#t=201704271430077417133).

Comment: Oh, and if you think versions are confusing, feel free to chime in on [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3773).

Comment: @omajid, in my quote of Julie Lerman, it's written that dotnet tell runtime version.

Comment: I know, I saw the link. I think Julie is wrong. Take a look at the bug I linked. It has .NET Core developers chiming in and explaining this. To quote blackdwarf: "The host and the runtime are distinct components.  The runtime version is not displayed anywhere, which is what @omajid is asking for (see response below on that)"

Comment: @omajid, but host and runtime, are they not the same? What is difference?

Comment: The "runtime" corresponds to the VM (coreclr) and the libraries/framework (corefx). The "host" is a tiny component (the `dotnet` binary) that selects the right "runtime" to use to run the application. That's pretty much all it does, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh. And in terms of github repos, *runtime* is https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx. *host* is https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup.

Comment: And things become even more fun when you realize you can have more than one runtime installed side-by-side in your .NET Core installation. The latest 1.0.4 update with the SDK, for example, includes both 1.0.4 and 1.1.1 runtimes. The 1.1.1 runtime is needed by the CLI/SDK itself.

Comment: When I run `dotnet`, it doesn't tell me any version. I think `dotnet --info` is a better choice.

Comment: @svick, dotnet shows version, dotnet --info shows .NET Command Line Tool (the same as SDK).

Comment: @Alex `dotnet` shows version of the "shared framework host" if you have only SDK 1.x installed. But that version is pretty much irrelevant. Which is why it doesn't show any version in 2.0 preview (which is what I have installed).

Comment: @svick, .NET Core 2? It doesn't exist yet. Or you mean NET Core tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @Alex I do mean [nightly build of .Net Core SDK 2.0.0 Preview 1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md).

Comment: @omajid, I asked this question on ASP.NET StandUp, they said that no command to show runtime version now, but they're working on it.

Comment: @svick, you're right about .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1 (just installed).

Comment: Understanding multiple .NET Core runtime versions: https://andrewlock.net/the-net-core-2-0-preview-1-version-numbers-and-global-json/